# Rails Session Files Missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The directory 'tmp' has folders like:

cache
pids
sessions
sockets

But they are always empty. When I restart my server, I get the the following error:

```
ActionController::SessionRestoreError
Session contains objects whose class definition isn\'t available.
Remember to require the classes for all objects kept in the session.
(Original exception: #{const_error.message} [#{const_error.class}])
```

My guess is because rails is unable to add to the tmp directory. I've tried chmoding it to 777 but no luck. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Rails' default session store should be a cookie store. Try clearing the cookies in your browser. It's probably storing a class that doesn't exist in your application anymore.

AFAIK, the tmp/sessions directory was used way back when the default session store was file storage. I'm not sure what it's used for these days. My tmp/sessions directory is always empty as far as I can tell.